# Overwrite array object if already present else add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

When I run this example I expect the `elementThatAllreadyExist` to overwrite the existing object with the name `test1` which it does correctly.

When I run the example with `arr2`, I expect the `newElement` element to be added to the array since no object with the `name` `"test33"` exists in the array, but no element is added to the array.

Why is it ignoring my `|| obj` fallback?

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "test1",
    values: {
      value1: 1,
      value2: 2,
      value3: 3,
    }
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    values: {
      value1: 1,
      value2: 2,
      value3: 3,
    }
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    values: {
      value1: 1
    }
  },
  {
    name: "test4",
    values: {
      value1: 1,
      value2: 2,
      value3: 3,
    }
  }
]

let elementThatAllreadyExists = [{
  name: "test1",
  values: {
    value1: 3323,
    value2: 2323,
    value3: 2323,
  }
}]

let newElement = [{
  name: "test33",
  values: {
    value1: 666,
    value2: 666,
    value3: 663,
  }
}]

const arr1 = arr.map(obj => newElement.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
console.log(arr1)

const arr2 = arr.map(obj => elementThatAllreadyExists.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: It's confusing that `elementThatAllreadyExists` and `newElement` are arrays of 1 element. What's the point of the array here? For the `newElement` code, how are you expecting that to be added? It doesn't match anything, so the `|| obj` branch runs for every element and you wind up with a shallow copy of the array `arr`. What output are you expecting?

Comment: I want to add these to the "arr" array and the overall purpose is to add elements to the array without generating dupplicate elements

Comment: Then call `arr.push(newElement[0])`? If you want that only to run if it's not already in the array, use `if (!arr.some(e => e.name === newElement[0].name)) { arr.push(newElement[0]) }`. `map` has nothing to do with adding new elements, it's purely for transforming existing elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer, when `.find()` returns null for every element in `arr`, as it does for `newElement`, then the `|| obj` fallback branch runs for every element and `map` returns a shallow copy. So it's not ignoring `|| obj` at all. In fact, that's all it's doing (when the element doesn't exist).

`map` doesn't add elements, it transforms existing elements. You can use `push` to do that.

As an aside, it's odd to have `newElement` and `elementThatAllreadyExists` as arrays of 1 element. These variable names should be pluralized if they're supposed to be arrays. If they're singular, remove the array to make them plain objects. Use `const` on all variable declarations you don't plan to reassign (which should be almost all of them).

Here's the function. If your inputs really are arrays, loop over them and invoke the `addOrReplaceExisting` function, but be warned that time complexity is quadratic. You might want to use a `Map` or object keyed by `name`. The `.set()` method already implements the "replace or add" behavior, implementing uniqueness on a key. Maps are O(1) for lookup and replacements.

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (arr, el, key="name") => {
  const existingIndex = arr.findIndex(e => e[key] === el[key]);

  if (existingIndex >= 0) {
    arr[existingIndex] = el;
  }
  else {
    arr.push(el);
  }
};

const arr = [{ name: "test1", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test2", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test3", values: { value1: 1 } }, { name: "test4", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } } ];
const elementThatAlreadyExists = { name: "test1", values: { value1: 3323, value2: 2323, value3: 2323, } };
const newElement = { name: "test33", values: { value1: 666, value2: 666, value3: 663, } };

replaceOrAdd(arr, elementThatAlreadyExists);
replaceOrAdd(arr, newElement);
console.log(arr);
```

Immuable version:

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (arr, el, key="name") => {
  const existingIndex = arr.findIndex(e => e[key] === el[key]);

  if (existingIndex >= 0) {
    return Object.freeze([
      ...arr.slice(0, existingIndex),
      el,
      ...arr.slice(existingIndex + 1),
    ]);
  }

  return Object.freeze(arr.concat(el));
};

const arr = Object.freeze([{ name: "test1", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test2", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test3", values: { value1: 1 } }, { name: "test4", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } } ]);
const elementThatAlreadyExists = { name: "test1", values: { value1: 3323, value2: 2323, value3: 2323, } };
const newElement = { name: "test33", values: { value1: 666, value2: 666, value3: 663, } };

const arr1 = replaceOrAdd(arr, elementThatAlreadyExists);
const arr2 = replaceOrAdd(arr1, newElement);
console.log(arr2);
```

`Map` version:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "test1", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test2", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } }, { name: "test3", values: { value1: 1 } }, { name: "test4", values: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3, } } ];
const elementThatAlreadyExists = { name: "test1", values: { value1: 3323, value2: 2323, value3: 2323, } };
const newElement = { name: "test33", values: { value1: 666, value2: 666, value3: 663, } };

const elemsByName = new Map(arr.map(e => [e.name, e]));
elemsByName.set(
  elementThatAlreadyExists.name,
  elementThatAlreadyExists
);
elemsByName.set(newElement.name, newElement);
console.log([...elemsByName.values()]); // or use .get to get a single element by name
```